Finding a surjective continuous map from $S^n$ to $T^n$, the $n$-torus

Question: Can one always construct a continuous surjective map from an $n$-sphere $S^n$ to an $n$-torus $T^n = \prod_{i=1}^n S^1$?

I believe the answer is yes. In fact an $n$-torus is a quotient space of an $n$-cell $e^n$, so if one can find a continuous surjective map from $S^n$ onto $e^n$, then there is a continuous surjective map onto $T^n$.
If $x \in S^n$ has coordinate $(x_1,...,x_{n+1})$, by identifying $(-x_1,,x_2...,x_{n+1})$ with $(x_1,...,x_{n+1})$, we can identify the north hemisphere with the south hemisphere continuously and the resulting quotient space is $e^n$, hence we have found a continuous surjective map onto $e^n$.
My argument certainly holds for $n=1,2$, but I'm uncertain with higher dimension cases. Please correct my argument if there's problem.

I guess you also want your map to be continuous?

@SeverinSchraven, Yes, but this map is continuous, right? I think we can define it alternatively, by mapping $(x_1,...,x_{n+1})$ to $(0,x_2,...,x_{n+1})$, which is a projection hence continuous.

I just thought it would be nice if you could add this requirement into your question.

@SeverinSchraven, Yeah, thank you for the suggestion

You can even map $[0,1]$ onto your favorite compact connected manifold.
